# Python 3.x - Enter n variables all in the same line

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new here. This is for a school project.

I would like to know how to enter user-defined number of variables in the same line

Sure, I know for:

a,b,c...= input().split()

But it does not help that much in my case, since problem involves n pairs of variables, so I need to input number of the pairs first, then all of them in the same line, like

n a[1] b[1] ... a[n] b[n]

And I'm really puzzled, it's easy with for loop but pairs are in new lines for sure. Is there any command that doesn't skip to the new line maybe? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: What is wrong with a list?

Comment: Nothing at all, it is basically a number and two lists. But for my assignment they ask to put it in the same line when entering, which is surely less readable and elegant. It turned out to be the bigger problem for me than the problem itself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One liner is certainly achievable, but won't look pretty. There's a relatively readable way of doing that in two lines:

```
inp = input().split()
n, a = inp[0], inp[1:]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Not a problem to have more code lines, but it needs to be in a single entering line while running. Which this does.

Basically if I understand well, you're building a list here, assigning first element to "n" and others to "a". The : syntax is new to me, we only used append.
I don't know if I can achieve pair structure easy like that, adding b? Elements with odd indexes would be "a" and even "b". Can it be donewith [2n:] or so?
I can think of adding for-if loop and making two lists out of it in the next step. Still, this seems too inelegant for such a small task.

Comment: I have solved the problem with the useful slice notation. Thanks for the directions!  <br/>

    `n, a, b = inp[0], inp[1::2], inp[2::2]`